# FastAPI Alembic - migrations files are not being created even though output says so. Folder "versions" is empty, and tables are missing from database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, alembic

I wanted to incorporate Postgresql into my FastAPI API. After a research I decided to follow this tutorial - https://youtu.be/NH4VZaP3_9s
And full code can be found here - https://github.com/veryacademy/YT_FastAPI_Beginner_Fast-Track

I checked several times and compared my code to tutorial one and I didn't find any differences.

But when I run command

```
docker-compose run my_api alembic revision --autogenerate -m "New Migration"
```

I got this output:

```
Creating my_api_my_api_run ... done
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'user'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_user_id' on '['id']'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'captcha_solve_query'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_captcha_solve_query_id' on '['id']'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'credits_transaction'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_credits_transaction_id' on '['id']'
  Generating /my_api/alembic/versions/858d5482faf8_new_migration.py ...  done
```

Yet my folder `versions` is still empty. I tried to search my mac for this file `858d5482faf8_new_migration.py` but it didn't return anything.

Anyway, I tried going along and executed next:

```
docker-compose run my_api alembic upgrade head
```

And I received this output:

```
Creating my_api_my_api_run ... done
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

Which starts to be a little bit weird because in the tutorial the output has additional line similar to this:

```
Running upgrade -> 858d5482faf8 New, Migration
```

And I am missing this line, still no errors though.

After that when I am either checking the postgres manually or try to do request, I am seeing/getting errors of missing tables, like I wouldn't do any migrations.

I am not sure what's going on, since I followed tutorial and I am not seeing any errors.
(I only get error about missing CSRF Token but I saw it as well in the tutorial so I guess it's not that?)

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

| | | | | EDIT | | | | | | | | | | EDIT | | | | | | | | | | EDIT | | | | |

I changed some things and kinda (?) managed to push it one step further (?). Commands from above still apply, but this time after I start docker I get this errors:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "postgresql_db" (192.168.80.2) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  database:
    container_name: postgresql_db
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    depends_on:
      - database

  my_api:
    container_name: my_api
    build: .
    command: bash -c "alembic upgrade head && uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: always
```

And here is my .env:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@postgresql_db:5432/my_api_db
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_NAME=my_api_db
PGADMIN_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
PGADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
```

I was googling about it, and common errors were using localhost instead of name of your container (that's not me I think), and specifying your postgresql address on home address (that's as well not me I think).

Comment: Can you share you docker-compose.yaml

Comment: @rfkortekaas Hi, I edited my post including more information, error text, docker-compose file and .env file. Thank you for replying!

Comment: Few notes. Alembic is storing the migration in `/my_api` but you are using a named volume `/app`. You don't have to expose the port if you're not going to connect it outside the docker context.

Comment: @rfkortekaas Thank you! The main problem was in named volume. I wouldn't notice it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Peksio, I'm not sure if I get it. How did you solve this problem? Can you please post detailed steps as an answer and accept it? Thanks